# Conductivity of electrically ionized water

Tags: electricity, water

So we see people putting salt in water for increased conductivity.

What if you ionize the water with voltage. Positive and negative splitting. One side will have more free electrons than the other right? Will that side then be a better conductor?

Comment: What makes you think you can ionize water with an electric field? If you supply a sufficient voltage to cause ionization I expect you will have catastrophic breakdown. I don't expect that you would be talking about concentration of electrons...

Comment: Two electrodes in water will cause ions to go to their respected sides right? Then half the water is leaning towards one charge and the other the opposite. Then if you scoop out some water from one side, will it be more or less electrically conductive than when it was all mixed as one?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In perfectly pure (demineralized) water there *are* no excess electrons or other particles. There are only water molecules. Nothing to accumulate on one side.

Since water molecules are *dipoles*, by adding a voltage across it you can *align* those molecules so their positive and negative ends, respectively, are pointing in the same direction. The positive end of each molecule is attracted to the side of lower potential; the negative end towards the side of higher potential. In total, the attraction to either side cancels out - such dipole only *aligns* (rotate), it doesn't move (translate).

(A high enough current can cause *dielectric breakdown*, like when lightning is suddenly conducted through otherwise insulating air - that requires a voltage large enough to actually *break* apart the molecules. I believe that is not your intention.)

Adding salt to water to make it conducting is simply done because salt dissolved into *ions*.  These ions have a net-charge and are positive and negative. They are *not* dipoles, so they *will* move (translate) at an applied voltage. And here you have your current carriers in the form of moving charges.

**Bottom line: Perfectly pure water is not conductive at all.** (Water in equilibrium *does* get a little bit partially ionized from smaller chemical reactions that break a few molecular bonds - see Floris' comment)

Comment: Perfectly pure water is partially ionized. At room temperature it has a concentration of $10^{-7}$ of $H_3O^+$ and the same of $OH^-$ ions! As such it is a **poor** conductor. It is wrong to say it is "not conductive at all".

Comment: Ok ok.. So voltage across it is aligning the molecules, not moving them. So in a bucket of water you would have all the ends pointing to the respected electrodes. Picturing iron shavings and a magnet. And thus over all this would kind of optimize the waters voltage potential.? Say if you removed the electrodes and took a reading at those points, everything would be aligned for the best points, of points to where the most voltage would be found?

But still does not move, only aligns. And thus taking water from either side would not give you the change in conductivity

Comment: @Equil I am not sure exactly what you are asking here. If you remove the electric field (the voltage) the positive dipole ends will repel and the alignment gets distorted randomly again.

Comment: Oh ok. Yea, I wasn't asking much :p Just making sure I digested it. So they don't stay aligned. I imagine you could freeze them real fast.. They have a state they want to occupy the most and that is defiantly not it. So.. ok. I have more questions. I am kind of pursing the idea of body radio. Hmm but anyway Ill have to make another post about that.

Comment: Can a field increase autoionization rates (OH- and H+/H3O) and separate them to a degree?